# Looping through custom react components and adding className's to them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array.prototype.map

I want to loop through custom React elements using `.map()`. An example of what i'm looping through is:

```
<Button text="Click me" />
<Button text="Click me" bgColor="yellow" textColor="black"/>
<Button text="Click me" bgColor="limeGreen" onClick={() => console.log('clicked')}/>
<Button text="Click me" bgColor="orchid"/>
<Button text="Click me" bgColor="rgb(150, 20,0)"/>
```

I have component called `Container` that takes these children as a property:

```
export const Container = ({children}) => {

    return (
        <div>{children}</div>
    )
}
```

I tried to implement the looping like:

```
const newChildren = children.map((item) => {
    //add class name to every item
})

//

<div>{newChildren}</div>
```

However I'm stuck at this point. How can I add a `className` attr to all of the items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`children` prop is a `ReactElement` (an **object** and **not** an array).

You need to use [`React.Children` API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap) in order to be able to map `children`.

Then use [`React.cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) for passing the `className` property.

Working Example:

```
// styles.js
.button {
  background: red;
}

// App.js
import "./style.css";

const Container = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child, key) =>
        React.cloneElement(child, { className: "button", key })
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <button>Give me some color!</button>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit angry-bardeen-fhblm]